# CSS: 100% div's not appearing as 100% on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float, width

Very odd but I have a site I'm working on (https://envymedical.com/staging/) and it's using Advanced Custom Fields to display a flexbox with two divs, side by side, on mobile and on phone, they should collapse and appear on top of one another.

For some reason, on mobile, this isn't happening even though I have a `width: 100%` set up for each div. Here's an example:

```css
.half_image_half_text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 25vw;
}

body.home .half_image_half_text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 40vw;
}

.half_image_half_text.reversed {
  flex-direction: row-reverse
}

.half_image_half_text .half-block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.half_image_half_text .text-block.watermark {
  background: url("../../images/envy-logo-bg.png") bottom left no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 759px) {
  .half_image_half_text {
    display: block;
    min-height: 60vw;
    height: 60vw;
  }
  .half_image_half_text .half-block {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .half_image_half_text .image-block {
    height: 60vw;
    max-height: 60vw;
  }
  body.home .half-block.image-block {
    width: 100%!important;
  }
  body.home .half-block.text-block.gray.invert {
    width: 100%!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="row half_image_half_text gray invert">
  <div class="half-block image-block" style="background-image:url('https://envymedical.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/hero-envy-medical-products.jpg')"></div>
  <div class="half-block text-block gray invert">
    <div class="block-text gray invert">
      <h2>Transformative Skin Care for Transformative Results</h2>
      <p><a class="btn" href="/our-products/">Shop Now</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this media you're changing the display to block:

```
@media (max-width: 759px) {
    .half_image_half_text {
        display: block;
        min-height: 60vw;
        height: 60vw;
    }
}
```

It doesn't allow to collapse the two divs because now it isn't a flex box, so if you keep it as a flex box then use `flex-direction: column` and it will solve the problem:

```
@media (max-width: 759px) {
    .half_image_half_text {
       flex-direction: column;
       min-height: 60vw;
       height: 60vw;
   }
}
```